# JavaFX add shapes to TilePane based on events in another class?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am trying to create an application which has a worker processes running in its own thread and GUI which based on what the worker is doing will update.I know how to use basic bindings but I would like to draw custom shapes and add them to different TilePanes which I have on my GUI, based on events in my worker class.

I can't figure out how to achieve this - all the bindings I am using are handled by JavaFX - for example I have tables which update the data based on what the worker is producing, but this is quite limiting. 
How can I create a new shape based on event running in another Thread (the worker class is completely separate from the GUI and I have to keep it that way in order to achieve as much as possible MVC pattern. Essentially I am looking for a way to invoke a method in my controller from another class (I need some sort of binding/listener which I have no idea how to do)

Also I don't want to create a massive Controller with everything inside but keep my worker class independent from the GUI implementation as much as possible.

Comment: For extra work in Java we use `Services` which are external Threads specifically made for extra work outside JAVAFX main Thread. Search tutorials for it. You can use `Platform.runLater(()->{°°})` inside them if you want to update the GUI as events occurring. Your question actually consists a lot of questions together. Have a look at the above please.

Comment: I am already using runLater when I want to update an observable list (part of my ModelData class) the data from  which is used in a TableView (using .setItems) My problem is that I want instead of binding properties from GUI components and those in my Data class, I want while my worker runs, to essentially change the UI by creating new Components etc. I don't know how to trigger method in my controller manually or on event in my worker class instead of relying on JavaFX observable list to do this for me as with the simpler case I have.

Comment: Typically you would use a MVC-type approach for this. Define a model class that has an observable list of some appropriate type (representing the data you are visualizing in the UI). Share a model instance between your worker class and your GUI (controller). The worker class can add items to the list: the GUI can register a listener with the list and when items are added, add shapes to the tile pane.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do, and actually I have it exactly like that but my observable list is just used with a TableView. The different Panes don't have any appropriate binding to create shapes. So all of the registering of listeners and so on is handled by JavaFX I don't need to do any of this. However now I want once the observable list changes, a custom handler to be bound to my Pane. Can't figure out how to do this.. I wanted to use JavaFX for its simplicity but now I am getting into dead end